# Listing file formats to represent georeferenced 3D data?

Tags: geometry, 3d, file-formats

I am looking for an overview of file formats that can store geo-referenced 3D geometries. There are no further requirements such as texture support, etc.

I have found the following formats so far and seek extensions to that list:

- Shapefile
- GML
- KML/KMZ
- GeoJSON

Comment: Do you have any other requirements? Because most GIS formats will support 3D data if you mean lat-lon-H or projected data with Z/elevation. I mean let's add Esri geodatabases, most RDBMS, DXF and DWG, etc.

Comment: I need a good and simple format to represent building geometries. Each building consists of a set of polygons. No further requirements.

Comment: I think this is a shopping list Question: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/should-shopping-list-questions-be-off-topic-and-closed-on-gis-stack-exchange

Comment: I wonder if you need to clarify further: I imagine there are (1) GIS formats that only allow 2D or 2.5D data -- no true 3D. (2) CAD formats that allow true 3D data but not geo-referenced. (3) True 3D GIS -- what you're asking about. And (4) Combo formats, like KML + DAE (Collada), that *together* provide what you ask for. Is that a useful classification?

Comment: @AndreSilva I was just highlighting that this looks like a Shopping List Question.  It is the reason why I voted to close it as too broad.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only talking about 3D geometry you can add the following:

- PostGIS
- Spatialite
- SketchUp
- OpenFlight

I create buildings in SketchUp, which can be exported to a number of different formats. If you load a georeferenced file, and building you make in SketchUp will inherent the georeferencing.

An equally important thing to consider is the means by which you want to view the building data.